# byebug: break on output to console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puts, byebug

I have some code (a Rails app) that generates output to console.

I'd like to use byebug to get the location of whatever is generating that output.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is the text printed by a method of which you know it's being called but don't know from where?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but ...

I'd love to trap every 'puts', etc., that puts any text to stdout.

Comment: Please have a look: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/README.md#from-within-the-ruby-code

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify a little more? What do you mean by having "the location of whatever is generating that output"? Do you mean the trace? If yes, buybug has a *backtrace* (you can use *where* also) command. Have you look into this?

EDIT:

You could use pry with byebug (with the [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug)) and accomplish what you want.

Comment: I am aware of backtrace.

What I'd love is some way to trigger a breakpoint when anything directs output to STDOUT

Answer (score 0):

Use pry gem for debugging code

## Gemfile

```
gem 'pry'
```

add binding.pry anywhere to debug code